# Allocating large arrays in memory with Python

Tags: python, memory, optimization

The code

```
import array, itertools
a = array.array('B', itertools.repeat(0, 3715948544))
```

takes almost 7 minutes to run on my machine (6m44s). The computer has 8 Gb of RAM and runs Linux with CPython 3.4.3. How can I obtain an array-like object with 1-byte unsigned int entries faster, preferably using the Python standard library? Numpy can allocate it instantly (in less than 1 millisecond).

Comment: Why are you preallocating it?

Comment: You should give up on the standard library and use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) instead

Comment: Wait, if you *know* NumPy can solve your problems, why did you ask the question?

Comment: @user2357112, I want to have as few external dependencies as possible, because I will distribute this code later and I don't want to bother with setting up a lot of libraries.

Comment: Numpy can allocate it almost instantaneously, but initialising it to zero still takes a few seconds.

Comment: What uses 3 billion values but isn't science-related enough where Numpy is an extremely low bar? Could you distribute it with Anaconda?

Comment: @NickT, Anaconda is a good option, thank you. However, as it has just turned out, for my purposes `numpy` arrays are slower than `bytearray`. Please see my comment to Sven's answer.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, I need random access. Please see my comment to Sven's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really can't use NumPy, you can try how far you can get with the built-in `bytearray`:

```
a = bytearray(3715948544)
```

This should finish in a couple of seconds at most.

Comment: This is about as fast as sequence multiplication from a different answer, approximately 1.95 seconds. Thank you!

Comment: @Pastafarianist It still has the same problem as the sequence multiplication  – you can't really do anything useful with the giant buffer after creating it without things becoming terribly slow.

Comment: I've just tested `bytearray` vs `array.array` vs `numpy`. In my particular case, `bytearray` is the fastest, `array.array` is a close second and `numpy` loses by a factor of almost 2. I am running a particular calculation, where this array is basically a huge counter: I read a value, add +1, write it back and check if it has exceeded a threshold. With `bytearray` I get about 7.5 sec/iteration, `array.array` is about 7.75 seconds and `numpy` is 14.6 seconds.

Comment: @Pastafarianist: Have you considered `collections.Counter`? Or just a regular dict? The 7.5 seconds number sounds like you aren't using anywhere near all the array cells. (That, or maybe you mean that one read/increment/write/check cycle takes 7.5 seconds, which is crazy slow.)

Comment: @user2357112, at each iteration I do 2^19 increments. A counter/dict won't do because in the end I will be using almost all of the entries.

Comment: @Pastafarianist: At that rate, using almost all the entries is going to take you about 14 hours, and that's if none of the counts go past 1. If the average value is 10, it'll take almost a week. You might want to look into Cython, or just write this in C. It sounded like a 7-minute startup lag was a deal-breaker, so 14 hours to a week of runtime probably isn't a great proposition.

Comment: @user2357112, a startup lag still makes debugging more painful than it should be. In any case, this whole thing was supposed to test a non-trivial optimization I've been trying to implement, and my implementation failed the test, so I changed my approach and at the expense of a little more resources I will probably no longer need to allocate large arrays in memory, at least not soon.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = array.array('B', [0]) * 3715948544
```

Sequence multiplication, analogous to how you'd create a giant list of zeros. Note that anything you want to *do* with this giant array is probably going to be as slow as your initial attempt to create it.

Comment: This takes about 2 seconds on my computer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought `numpy` would be fastest, but as pointed out by Sven, `bytearray` is pretty quick for 10000.  Try your luck with `bytearray` on 3billion.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import array, itertools

In [3]: %timeit array.array('B', itertools.repeat(0, 10000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 456 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit np.zeros(10000, dtype='uint8')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 924 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit bytearray(10000)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 328 ns per loop
```

Comment: Numpy is of course the best solution, since it's the only solution that allows you to actually do something with the array after creating it.